# Helps plus infinitive or gerund

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives

> This equipment helps improving people's lives.
>
> This equipment helps to improve people's lives.

Which one is correct?

Comment: @BillJ I think you meant "_help_ licenses infinitival complements"

Comment: @EddieKal Of course, thanks for spotting that. It should be "Help" licenses infinitival complements, but not gerund-participial ones. Note that for some speakers the "to" marker is optional.